# Using JSON libraries for parsing JSON to JavaObject

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, jackson, playframework-2.0

I'm using the IntelliJ Idea and Play Framework with Java. I send a request to the server and get a response in JSON format. But the response is huge and I actually need only one line from it. All the others can be ignored. How can I use this line further in my program as a `JavaObject`, and how can I ignore the other lines?

For ignoring other lines, I tried something like this:

> .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);

but it gives me an error saying:

> cannot find symbol  symbol:   DeserializationFeature

As I know, I can use Jackson library in Play Framework. I'm not sure if I used it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import play.libs.Json;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
...
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);

        return ok(response.toString());
    }
```

Here's the response in JSON format: https://pastebin.com/kh7pGiN5.

And here's the `build.sbt` from the Framework, as I am not sure I used the libraries correctly:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.8"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl
libraryDependencies += "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.9.13"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl
libraryDependencies += "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-core-asl" % "1.9.13"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.9.8"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.8"
```

Comment: You mixed it a little bit. Do not use `org.codehaus.*` dependencies. Only `com.fasterxml.*`. `Codehaus` is obsolete now. See on [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core). So, remove all `org.codehaus.*` dependencies and imports. How to use `Jackson` see [How do I read a data from a JSON file with high efficiency in Java with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906877/how-do-i-read-a-data-from-a-json-file-with-high-efficiency-in-java-with-jackson). Also which line in `JSON` do you need? See: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#get-it

Comment: @MichałZiober, thank you for the answer. So in dependencies I leave only three libraries, which are `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` and how I import them? This way: `import com.fasterxml.jackson.*`? I've already read the whole JSON data so now it is in StringBuffer format but I need not all of it, but only one line - the name of the province `"kind": "province", "name": "Bayern"`. That is what I thried to do with `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);` but there goes an error.

Comment: So, you need to load `JSON` from file and extract only object with `kind` equals to `province`. But in `JSON` you have many objects like this. Do you want to only one or all? Also, please, update question and provide exception stack trace.

Comment: @MichałZiober, from the JSON file I need only the name of the province of the first object (where the country is Germany)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use only `FasterXML` dependencies. Remove all `codehaus` dependencies. When you read `JSON` and you need only one or few elements you can read `JSON` as `JsonNode` and traverse it as a tree. To speed up traversing you can use `paths`: `/response/GeoObjectCollection/featureMember` to find `featureMember` array and `/GeoObject/metaDataProperty/GeocoderMetaData/Address/Components` to find `Components` array in each element of `featureMember`. See below app to find out all details:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
        GeoObjectWalker walker = new GeoObjectWalker(root);

        List<String> countries = Arrays.asList("Germany", "United States of America", "Austria", "Belgium");
        countries.forEach(country -> {
            final String message = "'%s' has first province: '%s'";
            System.out.println(String.format(message, country, walker.findProvinceForCountry(country).orElse("'not found'")));
        });
    }
}

class GeoObjectWalker {

    private final JsonNode root;

    public GeoObjectWalker(JsonNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public Optional<String> findProvinceForCountry(String country) {
        // find featureMember array
        JsonNode featureMembers = root.at("/response/GeoObjectCollection/featureMember");
        if (featureMembers.isMissingNode()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < featureMembers.size(); i++) {
            JsonNode featureMember = featureMembers.get(i);
            // find Components array
            JsonNode components = featureMember.at("/GeoObject/metaDataProperty/GeocoderMetaData/Address/Components");
            if (components.isMissingNode()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (componentsArrayContains(components, "country", country)) {
                Optional<String> province = findNameForKind(components, "province");
                if (province.isPresent()) {
                    return province;
                }
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private boolean componentsArrayContains(JsonNode array, String kind, String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonNode node = array.get(i);
            if (node.get("kind").asText().equals(kind) && node.get("name").asText().equals(name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private Optional<String> findNameForKind(JsonNode array, String kind) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonNode node = array.get(i);
            if (node.get("kind").asText().equals(kind)) {
                return Optional.of(node.get("name").asText());
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
'Germany' has first province: 'Bayern'
'United States of America' has first province: 'South Carolina'
'Austria' has first province: 'Oberösterreich'
'Belgium' has first province: 'Vlaams Brabant'
```