# Iterate over a large JSON Array with JSONPath

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, jsonpath

I have a simple `Java` app that needs to traverse a large `JSON` array (with around 20K items), and within each array, I parse a sub-array. Each item looks like this:

```
{"index":0,"f1":[2,16,16,16,16,16,32,16],"f2":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"startTime":0.0}
```

I am using `JSONPath` to iterate over each item. What I do is first I read the length, and simply iterate over the whole array. But it is very slow (like, 1 item per second).

```
int length = JsonPath.read(response, "$.result.length()");
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    double start_time = JsonPath.read(response, "$.result["+i+"].startTime");
    ArrayList<Integer> f1= JsonPath.read(response, "$.result["+i+"].f1");
    //...other things
}
```

Is there a way to optimise it?

Comment: Yes - first parse your JSON file into a data structure only once, and the you access the data structure. What you currently do is parsing the JSON every time you retrieve a value from it, which is, as you have noticed, very, very slow. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Can you elaborate more with snippets on `JSONPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Thanks to Erwin, I can parse the whole JSON at once into a `HASHMap` simply like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap> json= JsonPath.read(response, "$.result");
```

And then we can simply call `get(i)` to access a specific item in the loop:

```
double start_time = (double) json.get(i).get("startTime");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should minimise number of `read` operation. First time you scan the whole file and and next you scan `n` times file partially. Reading from disk is slower than from memory: [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832/), so you should load the file to memory once and then iterate over items. Also, from [`JsonPath`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) documentation:

> If you only want to read once this is OK. In case you need to read an
>   other path as well this is not the way to go since the document will
>   be parsed every time you call JsonPath.read(...). To avoid the problem
>   you can parse the json first.

```
String json = "...";
Object document = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(json);

List<Integer> f10 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.result[0].f1");
List<Integer> f11 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.result[1].f1");
```

You can improve your `JsonPath`: `$.result` and read only what you need by: `$.result..['f1','startTime']`.

Example app which loads only required fields:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        List<Object> array = JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$.result..['f1','startTime']");
        for (Object item : array) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) item;
            System.out.println(map.get("f1"));
            System.out.println(map.get("startTime"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is what I do now. Lighting speed now...unbelievable!

Comment: @TinaJ, I'm glad to hear that. We have more tools than only `JsonPath`, take a look on similar question with `Jackson` example: [How do I read a data from a JSON file with high efficiency in Java with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906877/how-do-i-read-a-data-from-a-json-file-with-high-efficiency-in-java-with-jackson). In case, my answer was helpful take a look on [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: fantastic answer @MichałZiober !